# need "crossdomain.xml" for my unity3d application

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml

I put my unity3d application on Facebook, but the login did not work because I need `crossdomain.xml` in the root of host according to [this doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html). I put it into my website, and it works for me , but not on Facebook. I think that it needs to be put it into the root of `app.facebook.com`.

This is my `crossdomain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: *"although this is not needed if it is the same domain that is hosting the unity3d file"*

Comment: i think it's not needed but when i put my application on facebook, i had a policy erreur crossdomain.xml not found :/

Comment: Your unity3d file is performing requests just for facebook domain?